# How to reference an glyph in iconfont by word?

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts, icon-fonts

I want to use iconfont in my project,and custom the font file by fontforge.

I know glyph can be referenced by unicode in html or css, such as `<i>&#xe030;</i>` and `&::before{content: "\e030";}`.While I find some people can reference glyph by this: `<i>library_music</i>`.I guess that's glyph name, but I cant find the 'library_music' definition in fontforge.

Here is my html and css code.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'testfont';
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v48/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');
}

i { font-family: "testfont"; }
```

```html
<i>library_music</i>
<i>&#xe030;</i>
```

I hope some one can tell me what is the principle of 'library_music' reference and how can I custom the word in fontforge.

thx a lot.

Comment: do you mean for this:https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/wGjyPO

Comment: @לבנימלכה Yes, that's what I want.Can you explain my question?thx

Answer (score 1):

As in [material guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs8tu.png) doc:

[image]

[here is explain](https://alistapart.com/article/the-era-of-symbol-fonts/)

Comment: I know that but sorry,look my example code.I did't use any class.The class you provided maybe used for `.icofont-address-book::before{content:"\eea3"}`.That didnt explain my  question.

Comment: thx.I see.There is another question,sry,I downloaded the woff file,then change the glyph at postion `e030` whose textual name is `library_music`.The icon changed successfully.Is that means every position which has it's own textual name can be customized?Will it cause some errors?Like name will be changed or causing poor performance ...